# What is going on in my Java code to make the answers negatives?

Tags: java

```
    public static int distanceBetweenMinAndMax (double[] list) {

    if (list == null || list.length == 0) return 0; 

    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) 
    {
        if (list[min] > list[i]) 
        {
            min = i;
        }
        if (list[max] < list[i]) 
        {
            max = i;
        }

    }
    int distanceBetweenMinandMax = max - min;
    return distanceBetweenMinandMax;
}
```

Okay, the point of the exercise is to find the distance from the max index to the min index. No matter what, my test cases are messing up. I'll be expecting 1 and get -1. Expect 3 and get -3. And so on. I assumed it had to be the int distance... = max - min line. But even if I flip them, the result is still negative.

I've tried everything for hours. Does anyone have any input on what may be wrong here that causes the answer to be negative?

NOTE: you just can't change the public static inc to a double.

Comment: Is your exercise really comparing the _indices_ of the list or the _values_ respectively? Anyway, on the first sight, it just seems to me, that your `<` and `>` are just the wrong way round. So to find the min, you should use `if (list[min] < list[i])` and `>` to find the max.

Comment: Can you perhaps add a test case that is calculated incorrectly?

Comment: You should return `Math.abs(max - min)`.

Comment: The point is to compare indices. So if you have [0,1,12] you want the result to be how many spaces apart they are. I also cannot use Math or import anything.

Comment: @ptoh64
REQUESTING CLARIFICATION
Please post the **exact** problem statement.
Your "Okay, the point of the exercise is to find the distance from the max index to the min index." is extremly confusing.

Comment: Must go through the array one time. Returns the difference between the index of the smallest integer in an array and the index of the largest number in an array.

Answer (score 1):

use Math.abs(min-max) -- because the index positions of Max and Min values can be crossed based on the input

int distanceBetweenMinandMax = Math.abs(min - max);

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
public static int distanceBetweenMinAndMax (double[] list) {

    if (list == null || list.length == 0) return 0; 

    double min = 0;
    double max = 0;
    int mxi=0;
    int mni=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
    {
        if (min > list[i]) 
        {
            min = list[i];
            mni=i;
        }
        if (max < list[i]) 
        {
            max = list[i];
            mxi=i;
        }

    }
    int distanceBetweenMinandMax = mxi - mni;
    return distanceBetweenMinandMax;
}
```

so if the result is (-) then max value is before the min value index
and if the result is (+) then max value is after the min value index

Comment: `the point of the exercise is to find the distance from the max index to the min index.`

Comment: Type mismatch error. Cannot convert a double to an int

Comment: change the type, i edited the solution, you can try any one, but last one is better

Comment: You're not allowed to here.

Comment: i got it, you want index distance, so edited the code, hope it will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```
int distanceBetweenMinandMax = max - min;
```

To:

```
int distanceBetweenMinandMax = max>min?(max-min):(min-max);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ptoh64 Your code is almost correct actually you get negative distance only when the max value comes earlier than the min value in the array. I mean the index of max value is less than the index of min value in array.

You have to return the absolute difference of max and min to avoid negative value for distance e.i

```
int distanceBetweenMinandMax = Math.abs(max - min)
```

The whole code will be same except above changes

```
public static int distanceBetweenMinAndMax(double[] list) {

        if (list == null || list.length == 0)
            return 0;

        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[min] > list[i]) {
                min = i;
            }
            if (list[max] < list[i]) {
                max = i;
            }

        }
        
        int distanceBetweenMinandMax = Math.abs(max - min);  // here take absolute difference
        return distanceBetweenMinandMax;
    }
```